# Android Linear Calendar java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime

So I am new to Android and have been working on a project to develop a linear calendar. While I have developed my code and there are no build errors, there are however runtime errors and I have no idea how to fix them.

```
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cs.nuim.ie.finaltimeline/cs.nuim.ie.finaltimeline.MainActvity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cs.nuim.ie.finaltimeline.MainActvity
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cs.nuim.ie.finaltimeline.MainActvity
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
12-05 08:51:54.116: E/AndroidRuntime(611):  ... 11 more
```

Here is my MainActivity where the error is arising

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String LogTag = "drgn";

// TODO move timer thing to view itself
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        contentView.postInvalidate();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 250);
    }
};

private TLView contentView;
private CalStuff calstuff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    calstuff = new CalStuff(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    contentView= (TLView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

}
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    calstuff.LoadCalendars();
    Log.d(LogTag, "calendars loaded: " + calstuff.ourCalendars.size());

    calstuff.LoadEvents();
    Log.d(LogTag, "events loaded: " + calstuff.ourEvents.size());

    /*
     * calstuff.LoadInstances(); Log.d(LogTag, "instances loaded: " +
     * calstuff.ourInstances.size());
     */

    contentView.SetCalStuff(calstuff);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(LogTag, "pause");
    super.onPause();

    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(LogTag, "resume");
    super.onResume();

    runnable.run();
}

}
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: For some reason it's looking for a class named `MainActvity` notice the spelling error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought, but have you checked your Manifest file? There is, as pointed out by EWit, a spelling error in the class name (MainActvity vs MainActivity). I think that could come from your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue occurs while including in `AndroidManifest` reference with:

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and hardcoded wrong `google_play_services_version` value.